# Connecting to two ISP in local network using two different network

Tags: networking, internet, network-manager

We have two ISP 1. BSNL (INDIA), 2. Airtel (INDIA). we getting Bsnl internet through D-Link DSL 2750U modem which holds the IP 192.168.1.1, Airtel internet modem with 192.168.2.1 IP address, Here it's both are from different network. Mostly Bsnl internet not being stable annoying service provider. When ever BSNL internet unstable i want to get use the airtel without changing any configuration are manually routing every time. We have mostly all client machines in Linux (Ubuntu), Centos.

This is the interface configuration now i'am using in Ubuntu

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
        address 192.168.1.25
        network 192.168.1.0
        netmask 255.255.255.0
        broadcast 192.168.1.255
        gateway 192.168.1.1
        dns-nameservers 8.8.8.8 8.8.4.4
        bridge_ports eth0
        bridge_stp off
        bridge_fd 0
        bridge_maxwait 0
        post up route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 gw 192.168.2.1
```

Just i have tried to route from 192.168.1.0 to 192.168.2.0 using route add in interface, But still there is no ping reply from 192.168.2.1. Did i want to add one more interface config for 192.168.2.0 using alias ? Any help will be mostly appreciated.

All i need to know how can i configure now while we have two internet connections, with 2 different modem with two different network range one is 192.168.1.1 IP range and other with 192.168.2.1 But my desktop and all client machines ip range was 192.168.1.0 series, My need here is when ever my internet which in 192.168.1.1 goes down i have to get the internet from 192.168.2.1 modem.

Answer (score 0):

What you are trying to implement is called as multihoming. Check the link [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/596644/cant-reach-multi-homed-ubuntu-from-different-subnet) and [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/614333/trying-to-setup-multi-homing-under-ubuntu12-but-can-only-get-1-of-2-ip-to-accept). These will give you an idea.